# VBA Outlook script - If Or statement returning wrong value

Tags: vba, outlook

```
 MName = Format(dtDate, "mm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

 If MName = "04" Or "06" Or "09" Or "11" Then 
        DName = "30"
    ElseIf MName = "02" Then
        DName = "28"
    ElseIf MName = "01" Or "03" Or "05" Or "07" Or "08" Or "10" Or "12" Then
        DName = "31"
    Else
 End If
```

I'm creating this script to save down email attachments to folders that are named based on month-end. For example, if the email is sent on 10-25-16 it will be saved to the 10-31-16 folder.

The issue occurs when determining what month-end day to use. The "MName" is equal to 10 (for October). However, the "DName" returns as "30" when it should return as "31" when the MName is equal to "10".

Any ideas why this is triggering the first line of the If statement? Thanks in advance!

Comment: David has given u great example on how to use Or but I like using 'Select Case' ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how an [`Or` operator works in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264205.aspx). `Or` is a boolean operator which works like:

```
> result = expression1 Or expression2
```

In your case, you have:

```
If MName = "04" Or "06" ...
```

And in this usage, "06" is itself an expression, you're saying:

```
If (MName = "04") Or ("06") Or (expression3) Or ...
```

So this is why your results are not what you expect.

Consider using a `Case` statement instead:

```
Select Case MName
    Case "04", "06", "09", "11"
        Dname = "30"
    Case "30"
        DName = "28"
    Case "01", "03", "05", "07", "08", "10", "12"
        DName = "31"
    Case Else
        DName = "" 'Modify if needed...
End Select
```

To do this with `If` statements is a lot messier.

```
 If MName = "04" Or MName = "06" Or MName = "09" MName = Or MName = "11" Then 
        DName = "30"
    ElseIf MName = "02" Then
        DName = "28"
    ElseIf MName = "01" Or MName = "03" Or MName = "05" _
                    Or MName = "07" Or MName = "08" Or MName = "10" Or MName = "12" Then
        DName = "31"
    Else
 End If
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now. Thanks so much for the help and the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

Each OR operator starts a new condition, so you have to add MName = to each.

```
MName = Format(dtDate, "mm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

 If MName = "04" Or MName = "06" Or MName = "09" Or MName = "11" Then 
        DName = "30"
    ElseIf MName = "02" Then
        DName = "28"
    ElseIf MName = "01" Or MName = "03" Or MName = "05" Or MName = "07" Or MName = "08" Or MName = "10" Or MName = "12" Then
        DName = "31"
    Else
 End If
```

You may be better off using the CASE function.

```
MName = Format(dtDate, "mm", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

Select Case CInt(MName)
    Case 4 To 5
        Debug.Print "hi"
    Case 6, 7, 8
        Debug.Print "ho"
    Case 9 To 10
        Debug.Print "hum"
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "error!"
End Select
```

Where instead of my debug.print, you place DName = "XX".

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and the lesson!